# Deploy Flask API on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python-3.x, flask, deployment, pythonanywhere

I have a Flask app with python3.10.4 and I want to deploy it on PythonAnywhere.

I [changed the system image](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ChangingSystemImage) and followed [the deployment instructions](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/). It deployed successfully, but the homepage says "Hello from Flask!" instead of my index route's content.

So, I tried [this suggestion](https://pythonhow.com/python-tutorial/flask/deploy-flask-web-app-pythonanywhere/), changing `app.py` to `flask_app.py` and uploading, but now the homepage breaks saying:

> There was an error loading your PythonAnywhere-hosted site. There may be a bug in your code. Error code: Unhandled Exception.

So I deleted `flask_app.py` and uploaded `app.py` back, but it's still broken. How do I fix this?

## EDIT

This was my pythonanywhere wsgi.py

```py
import sys

# Add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/<username>/<sitename>'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(project_home)

# Import the Flask app, but name it "application" for WSGI to work
from app import app as application
```

Note that `<username>` and `<sitename>` were my actual username and sitenames.

### Attempts and progress

I realized pythonanywhere overwrites my `app.py` with their own, so I edited and debugged. So far it only works if I comment out scheduler, and if I don't click 2 broken URLs.

```py
# app.py
# imports...

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True  # required to access flask-apscheduler API
initialize_databases()

scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
# scheduler.add_listener(error_listener, EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
# scheduler.start()  # TODO this is a deployment bug

# Register the API blueprint
app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')


@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
    """
    Returns a JSON object containing all accessible API links, or rendering that on homepage.html.
    """
    # Fetch the jobs JSON from the /api/enabled_jobs endpoint
    with app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.get("/api/enabled_jobs")
        jobs_json = response.json

    api_links = []
    for rule in current_app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if rule.endpoint != 'static' and '/api/' in rule.rule and '/schedule/' not in rule.rule:
            api_links.append(str(rule))
    return render_template('homepage.html', jobs=jobs_json, links=api_links, page_links=page_links)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"code begins {dt.datetime.now()}")
    app.run(port='5001')  # coz MacVentura Airplay uses port 5000
```

...but this is not okay, because they need to be functional.

Comment: Could you add the contents of your WSGI file (there's a link to it on the "Web" page inside PythonAnwyhere) to your post?

Comment: @GilesThomas I edited the post in response to your request.

Comment: With such errors (on PythonAnywhere) it's good to check the error log (it's linked to on the Web page).  By reading your `app.py` file, I assume that the webapp fails because of the Appscheduler, which won't work in the web app.  If you use a paid account, you could put the scheduler bit into an Always-on task.

Comment: @caseneuve I edited the post with the error log.

Comment: @Silcrow it looks rather like the access log, actually

Comment: @caseneuve you're right, I updated the error log

Comment: I found the issue with the index page, but the debugging is ongoing. I updated the post.

Comment: Cool (btw I mentioned `Appscheduler` as the most probable culprit above).

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering myself to close this thread:

PythonAnywhere overwrites my `app.py` with their own, so I had to manually edit it in PythonAnywhere's File tab.

So far it only works if I comment out scheduler, and if I don't click 2 broken URLs, but that should be for a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493488/calling-external-api-with-flask-deployed-on-pythonanywhere).

Comment: PythonAnywhere is not overwriting any of your files, it only generates a UWSGI file for each deployed web app, which the user has to edit so it matches their configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow's culture. So should I delete this answer?