# Calling external API with Flask deployed on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere, flask-cors

I deployed Flask app on PythonAnywhere but an api that calls an external APScheduler api `/scheduler/jobs` fails. It keeps loading endlessly and then the entire website breaks. Everything worked fine in local host.

I added CORS to my app to allow pythonanywhere's host name in `app.py`:

```py
# app.py
# imports and flask app initialization...
cors = CORS(app)

@app.after_request
def add_cors_headers(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 
    'https://<username>.pythonanywhere.com'
    return response
# the rest of the code...
```

I can curl in pythonanywhere's bash: `curl -X GET http://<username>.pythonanywhere.com/scheduler/jobs` and also do the same in Postman.

I checked my code and everything worked until I uncomment `requests.get()`, it fails. There are no error logs for this one.

```py
@api_bp.route('/jobs_details', methods=['GET'])
def get_jobs_details():
    jobs_data = fetch_scheduler_jobs(request)

def fetch_scheduler_jobs(request):
    # Fetch from builtin API
    base_url = request.host_url.rstrip('/')
    url = f"{base_url}/scheduler/jobs"
    headers = dict(request.headers)
    # response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return headers
```

## Desperate attempts

I tried using curl directly in the code, but that also doesn't work:

```py
def make_curl_request(url, headers=None):
    """
        Hotfix to replace `requests.get(url, headers=headers)`
        :param url:
        :param headers:
        :return:
    """
    command = ['curl', '-X', 'GET']
    if headers:
        for header in headers:
            command.extend(['-H', header])
    command.append(url)
    result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True)
    response_body = result.stdout
    response_dict = json.loads(response_body)
    return response_dict


def fetch_scheduler_jobs(request_obj):
    # Fetch from builtin API
    base_url = request_obj.host_url.rstrip('/')
    url = f"{base_url}/scheduler/jobs"
    headers = [f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in request_obj.headers.items()]
    response = make_curl_request(url, headers=headers)
    return response
```

error log:

```bash
2023-06-18 19:35:37,209: Exception on /api/jobs_details [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<usernam>/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/<usernam>/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/<usernam>/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/<usernam>/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/<usernam>/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/<usernam>/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/<usernam>/<projname>/api/routes.py", line 29, in get_jobs_details
    jobs_data = fetch_scheduler_jobs(request)  # TODO 1. deployment bug
  File "/home/<usernam>/<projname>/api/api_utils.py", line 39, in fetch_scheduler_jobs
    response = make_curl_request(url, headers=headers)
  File "/home/<usernam>/<projname>/api/api_utils.py", line 30, in make_curl_request
    response_dict = json.loads(response_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But the error with `make_curl_request()` is unrelated to the original error, which is using `requests.get()` to an external API.

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in the error log?  Are you using a paid account on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: no it's a free account, yes there are some error logs after trying make_curl_request() but I really want to make it work the proper way

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you use curl and not a Python module dedicated to the job (like `requests`)?  Anyway, I'd add some logging, and check if `response_body` in that function is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I used requests and it didn't work, and won't show error logs because the page loads endlessly. `make_curl_request()` was just my hacky method of desperation. Thanks for diving in.

Comment: A free account only has one worker, so you cannot make a request to the site from a request that was made to the site because the worker is already dealing with the first request.

Comment: I see, so I have to deploy to other clouds (or wait or find such a cloud) that might provide more workers for a free account? I don't know how to self-deploy other than localhost and I don't want to turn on any personal laptop or device 24/7.